# Linking parallel coordinates to an image and making change in that image

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

Imagine I have a set of images (number of images : N), and in each image there are several circles.

I have used image processing algorithms to extract 10 features from each image. Among those 10 features I have the center coordinate (cx and cy ) for that specific circle.

For a specific image with m circles in it, I will have an array of m by 10 (m is the number of circles in that image). So the results will be an array of N*m by 10.

I have written a Javascript code using D3, that draws parallel coordinates for those 8 features (not cx and cy). Now, I want to add a specific capability to my parallel coordinates, that by hovering on different lines (different circles), related image is shown and also the center of that specific circle in the image can be recognized. Please see the image below.

I don't know if it is possible using Javascript and D3 or not. I would be thankful if anyone can help me through this or give me a similar example.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally possible. As I don't have a JSFiddle or code example, I am going to give some high level ideas:

1. The circles on image is very straight forward. Just render the image in <img> tag. Overlay a canvas with transparent background and draw all the circles/ovals.
2. I believe you used SVG path for each circle (lines going through each of the feature values). Get a handle to the SVG path element on mouseover. Determine the index of the circle in question.
3. Once you have the index, look up (cx, cy) and render the center for the circle in the canvas. On mouseout, remove the center asterisk.

Hope that helps!